# Xpages ObjectData Custom Control: Mixing compositeData with text

Tags: xpages

Would like to make a custom control for my DataObjects which would have two properties, the javaClass and the javaModel.

So if I have a java class names acme.com.model.Person, the javaClass property would be acme.com.model.Person and the javaModel property would be Person.

I started to build my custom control but only got a few things put in before I ran into syntactical problems.

The real problem is createObject. I don't understand how I can replace the presently hard-coded "Person" in the createObject with my compositeData values. Is this even possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
        <xp:this.data>
        <xe:objectData
            saveObject="#{javascript:compositeData.javaModel + 'save()'}"
            var="${javascript:compositeData.javaModel}">
            <xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:var Person = new com.scoular.model.Person();
var unid = context.getUrlParameter("key")
if (unid != "") {
    Person.loadByUnid(unid);
    viewScope.put("readOnly","Yes");
} else {
    Person.create();
    viewScope.put("readOnly","No");
}
return Person;}]]></xe:this.createObject>
        </xe:objectData>
        </xp:this.data>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as you might try to de-couple your business logic from your "UI" (XPages markup), you could move your "create" code to a constructor method to the `Person` class, one which:

- calls out to check for the URL Parameter of "key"
- sets the key to a property (making this a bit more bean-like, optional, but likely a good idea)
- invokes the `loadByUnid(String)` method
- and puts the appropriate `readOnly` value into `viewScope`

```java
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    // constructor method
    public Person(){
        Map<String, Object> reqParm = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String unid = (String) reqParm.get("key");
        Map<String, Object> vwScope = ExtLibUtil.getViewScope();
        if (unid != "") {
            this.loadByUnid(unid);
            vwScope.put("readOnly","Yes");
        } else {
            this.create();
            viewScope.put("readOnly","No");
        }
    }
    //...

}
```

Then your `createObject` block would look more like:

```xml
<xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:return new com.scoular.model.Person();}]]></xe:this.createObject>
```

This should shift enough of the specifics off of the markup layer so as to be far more reusable across specific classes, provided each self-construct like that.

As for the general mixing `compositeData` with text, you should be passing an object reference so for the example of the save method above, I think you should be able to access it more via `compositeData.javaModel.save();`, provided the `save` method exists in the object referenced by `compositeData.javaModel`. I don't think appending the string of a method will work, but I can't say I've tried it that way.

Comment: My pleasure @BryanSchmiedeler.