# Xpages Custom Control: Putting compositeData value in an SSJS Function

Tags: xpages

I am posting the code that I used to solve this. Thanks to Per and Eric McCormick and Paul Withers.

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(
function() { 
x$("#{javascript:return getComponent(compositeData.fieldName).getClientId(facesContext);}").select2({
                                placeholder : "Choose an employee",
                                allowClear: true,
                                minimumResultsForSearch : 3
                            })  
}
);                      
]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

The answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709010/xpages-objectdata-custom-control-mixing-compositedata-with-text) was incredibly useful. I am making a Select2 custom control and need to use the dynamically generated ID in an SSJS function

I am dynamically creating the id of the field in the custom control by giving it the fieldName, like so:

```
id="${javascript:compositeData.fieldName}"
```

In other parts of my CC I use that computation to access the id number, for example:

```
    <xp:message 
            id="message1"
            for="#{javascript:compositeData.fieldName}"
            styleClass="help-block">
        </xp:message>
```

However in building my Select2 CC I need to add some SSJS in script, like so:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                x$("#{id:[compositeData.fieldName]}").select2({
                placeholder: "Select An Employee",
                allowClear: true
                });
                }
                );
]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

But this doesn't work. I cannot figure out how to dynamically generate the ID.

```
x$("#{id:[compositeData.fieldName]}")


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    id="view1">



    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                x$("#{id:[compositeData.fieldName]}").select2({
                placeholder: "Select An Employee",
                allowClear: true
                });
                }
                );
]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>


    <xp:div>
    <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"form-group" + (getComponent(compositeData.fieldName).isValid() ? "" : " has-error")}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
            <xp:label
            styleClass="control-label"
            for="#{javascript:compositeData.fieldLabel}"
            value="${compositeData.fieldLabel}" />
            <div class="">

            <xp:comboBox 
                id="${javascript:compositeData.fieldName}"
                value="#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName]}"
                required="${compositeData.required}">
                <xp:selectItems
                        value="${javascript:'#{CacheBean.'+compositeData.cacheItem+'}'}">
                    </xp:selectItems>
                <xp:this.validators>
                    <xp:validateRequired message="#{javascript:compositeData.fieldLabel + ' is required'}"></xp:validateRequired>
                </xp:this.validators>
            </xp:comboBox>

            <xp:scriptBlock
                id="scriptBlock1">
            <xp:this.value>
            <![CDATA[x$("#{id:comboBox5}").select2({minimumResultsForSearch:5});]]>
            </xp:this.value>
            </xp:scriptBlock>

            <xp:text
                    escape="true"
                    id="computedField1"
                    styleClass="help-block"
                    value="${compositeData.helpText}">
                    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:(getComponent(compositeData.fieldName).isValid()) && compositeData.helpText != null}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            </xp:text>

            <xp:message 
                id="message1"
                for="#{javascript:compositeData.fieldName}"
                styleClass="help-block">
            </xp:message>
        </div>

    </xp:div>


    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2"      
        value="${javascript:'#{id.'+compositeData.fieldName+'}'}">
    </xp:text>


</xp:view>
```

Comment: what about using standard onClientLoad with only x$(... call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the dynamically generated id from client side JS (using SSJS) by using the SSJS function `getClientId()`. So in your case it will look like this combined with the x$ function:

```
x$('#{javascript:getClientId(compositeData.fieldName)}')
```

Comment: Per thanks of this answer. With a few tweaks that worked! I have updated my question to post the eventual code that I used.